# CSS Nested Fixed Position

Tags: html, css

I am just trying to create one layout which have fixed header. I need to have one mask in the header so i added one more div for that. The following are my code;

**Html:**

```
<div>
  <div class="fixed-parent">
    <div class="fixed-child">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is..</p>
    <p>Contrary to popular belief...</p>
    <p>The standard chunk...</p>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fixed-parent {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index:1;
}
.fixed-child {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.content
{
    position: absolute;
    top:105px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0;

}
```

In desktop, it working perfect. When i checked in mobile browser / webview, the header part is flickering (child div is moving) when scrolling. This is happened when i check in sharp mobile.

When i put the child div as separate div, there is no issue.

Please confirm, this is expected behavior or something like that.

Comment: What mobile browser is it that you are testing with? I just tested your code with Android 6 and everything works as expected.

Comment: You seem to have a missing closing `</div>` at the end of your HTML block.

Comment: The issue in webview in sharp mobile. I event didnt got in samasung galaxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to specify the parent DIV position as fixed. Try removing that for the child DIV and check if it works on your mobile.

```css
.fixed-parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.fixed-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-parent">
  <div class="fixed-child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
  <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes its fine. Also if i didn't nested (put as separate div) also working. Is this expected behaviour

Comment: When the DIVs are not nested, they are rendered sequentially with the later DIV on top of the earlier one (in your specific case).

Answer (score 0):

Add `top:0` to your **header** and **header** it won't flicker in mobile device,

```
.fixed-parent {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
}
```